# Cannot start Apache (c:/php/php5apache2_4.dll into server: The specified module could not be found)

Tags: php, apache, dll

Well I tried to install PHP 5.5.9 and I followed the procedure in this video exactly: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Y6lOHov3Bk

Basically I pasted these lines in the httpd.conf file, saved and restarted my computer.

```
# For PHP 5 do something like this:
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_4.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

# configure the path to php.ini
PHPIniDir "C:/php"
```

And now when I try to start Apache it does not work, and the last line in the error log is the following.

```
(Cannot start Apache (c:/php/php5apache2_4.dll into server: The specified module could not be found)
```

The only thing I can think is that when I downloaded the PHP 5.5.9 zip file and unpacked it, it did not have the php5apache2_4.dll file so I had to download it from a 3rd party website: http://download12.mediafire.com/9ory5zibr0zg/ncwlddm9cclwc99/php5apache2_4.dll

Comment: The lines "For PHP 5 do something like this:", "configure the path to php.ini" are meant to be comments but when you put the # symbol next to a line of code it makes it bold when you post it instead.

Comment: By the way, when I comment out the lines of code that I pasted into the conf file, the server will start.

Comment: This happened to me after an update. I had to repair "Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable (x64/86)" under Programs and Features in windows10

Answer (score 4):

You don't state whether you have `x86` or `x64`, but the `php5apache2_4.dll` is only in the *Thread Safe* binary.

http://windows.php.net/download/

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue in windows 7 64bit Pro, when installed wampserver3.0.4_x64_apache2.4.18_mysql5.7.11_php5.6.19-7.0.4.exe.

The error in windows Event Viewer (though the file was there) :
The Apache service named  reported the following error:

> > > httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 184 of C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.18/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load c:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.19/php5apache2_4.dll into server: The specified module could not be found.

Soultion :

Try 1: First installed vc_redist.x64.exe as suggested by others (did not solve the problem)

Try 2:

```
Modified the below line in C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.18\conf\httpd.conf
//old line
#LoadModule php5_module "c:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.19/php5apache2_4.dll"
//New line
LoadModule php7_module "c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.4/php7apache2_4.dll"
```

After this WAMP can start, icon shows green, I can use for my developments.

Note : Another wamp related problem still exists in my system, when I click on the green wamp icon, the wamp menu does not open. I am researching now to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need Microsoft VC++ 2012 distributable installed for PHP 5.6 to work. Once you install this, it should work fine for this.

Here is the configuration

```html
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_4.dll"

<IfModule php5_module>

   # configure the path to php.ini
   PHPIniDir "C:/php"
   AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
</IfModule>
```